# QuantLib Boost_1_72 VS2019 Build Error : "Cannot open include file boost/config.hpp: no such file or directory"

Tags: boost, quantlib

Just tried installing QuantLib and Boost with VS2019 but unable to build the solution. It throws this error

"Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory"

Followed various help pages but no luck. One thing to notice is that everyone seems to be talking about the "Property Manager" which I don't seem to fund in VS2019.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuLHW.png)

Comment: is it supposed to be config.php ?

Comment: config.hpp is correct. It's a C++ header file.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the installation instructions on the official QuantLib site](https://www.quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml):

> 5. Open the Property Manager by clicking on View/Property Manager and activate it.

That would be the "View" in the menu bar. Once you have it open,

> Earlier Visual C++ versions used Microsoft.cpp..users files for global settings. However, these files are now deprecated and, depending on your Visual C++ version, might no longer be available. If that is the case, or if you want to follow Microsoft's advice anyway, create a new property page as described at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019), add it to all projects in the solution, and use that instead of the .users files.

The link mentioned in the instructions above is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019, from the Visual Studio documentation. It will guide you to create the properties you need.

Comment: Thanks Luigi. #5 and the snippet in your post, from the installation link, is what I was trying. I figured out (thanks to the microsoft link), in VC2019 there is no View->Property Manager. Instead it has been moved to View->Other Windows->Property Manager. Following instruction made the code build like a charm.

Also, I tried selectin gall projects in the solution earlier, right-click to get the Property Page and then set the path to boost folder/library and even that worked.